# ADB copy the newest file

Tags: android, windows, command-line, adb, toybox

I am using the following command to copy the most recently added file from a connected device into the directory that I want:

```
adb pull sdcard/Robotium-Screenshots/filename.jpg D:\jenkins\jobs\
```

But it can copy only the file that I specify.

How can I copy the newest file from `sdcard/Robotium-Screenshots/` to `D:\jenkins\jobs\` without specifying it by name?

Comment: I think you might need to write a script to identify the first file, and then execute the adb pull

Answer (score 2):

Here is a one-liner which would pull the last modified file from a specified folder:

```
adb exec-out "cd /sdcard/Robotium-Screenshots; toybox ls -1t *.jpg 2>/dev/null | head -n1 | xargs cat" > D:\jenkins\jobs\latest.jpg
```

Known limitations:

- It relies on `ls` command to do the sorting based on modification time. Historically Android devices had multiple sources for the `coreutils`, namely `toolbox` and `toybox` multi-binaries. The `toolbox` version did not support timestamp based sorting. That basically means that this won't work on anything older than Android 6.0.
- It uses `adb exec-out` command to make sure that binary output does not get mangled by the `tty`. Make sure to update your `platform-tools` to the latest version.

Comment: How to do the same thing but with the name of the latest file instead of "latest"?

Answer (score 1):

If you use a bash-like shell, you can do:

```
adb pull /sdcard/Robotium-Screenshots/`adb shell ls -t /sdcard/Robotium-Screenshots/ | head -1` ~/Downloads
```

You can get a bash-like shell through cygwin, msys, git for windows (based on msys). If you are on mac or linux, you already have a bash-like shell.

Comment: What do the code quoted adb shell mean inside adb pull and why does this return the full path?

Comment: The back tick is for substituting the result of the command, so it will substitute with the filename of the last modified file. It only returns the filename which is why I put the full path of the folder twice.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to grab the file name using the following command:

```
adb shell ls -lt /sdcard/Robotium-Screenshots | head -n2 | tail -n+2 | awk '{print $8}'
```

Comment: vTad is using windows and in your command `head`, `tail` and `awk` are being run on the host side.  by using `-1` instead of the `-l` option you could have eliminated both `tail` and `awk`. Also when you need to limit your input to a specific line and you are already using `awk` - there is no need to use the `head` and `tail` combination - just use `awk`'s built-in `NR` variable